# Use of this and super within local classes defined in a static context

Tags: java, static, this, inner-classes

I was going through the following code while studying Java local classes :-

```
class A {
  protected int one;
}

class Outer {

   static void staticMethod(){            
       class InnerLocal extends A {
           double first = this.one;
           double second = super.one;      
       }
   }

}
```

My doubt is that when we declare the local classes inner to static method or static initializer block then they implicitly work as static member classes as they need no outer class to instantiate them. However I know the difference clearly between a static member class and static local class(i.e. the inner class defined in static block), the problem is that Java does not allows the object references 'this' and 'super' to be used in static context but the code above compiles perfectly.

Can anyone please provide me the reason why Java compiler doesn't complains on using 'this' and 'super' in static context in the above case? Thanks!:)

Comment: Because you are defining instance variable of this local class. So `this` will be the instance of `InnerLocal` you are building. Set those two as `static` to get the problem you expect.

Comment: There is no static context in your example code. `this` refers to the instance of `InnerLocal` and `super` refers to the `A` parts of the instance of `InnerLocal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My doubt is that when we declare the local classes inner to static method or static initializer block then they implicitly work as static member classes as they need no outer class to instantiate them

This is the root cause of your confusion. Just because a method is `static` does not mean that anything declared within the method is also `static`. If you declare a variable (say `int a`) inside a `static` method, it is said to be a local variable. It would make no sense to say that `a` is a method local `static` variable. Similarly, it would make no sense to say that `InnerLocal` is a method local `static` class. (There is no such thing as `static` local variable in Java)

`InnerLocal` is therefore a regular class that extends from `A` and inherits the `a` member variable from `A` and is able to access it either through `this` or through `super`. It would also help to know that `final` is the only non-access modifier that can be used within a method in Java.

Comment: Thanks @CKing now it's more clear, just another favour tell me if i have understood it correctly or not : in the above program the class `InnerClass` is a static inner class but it has only one feature or property that makes it look similar to static classes is that it requires no Outer class instance to instantiate itself and rest of it works as the normal class that is it can make use of 'this' and 'super' as any normal class. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere and also guide me if I am still missing any aspect. Thanks!

Comment: @prateek.1729 `InnerLocal` is a method local inner class and is not a `static` class (as already explained in the answer). Not sure why you are still saying that it is a static class. Can you elaborate? Also, if you removed `static` keyword from `staticMethod()` so that the method is no longer a `static` method, you will still be able to instantiate `InnerLocal` within the method without the need of an `Outer` instance.

Comment: I am just using the word 'static' to differentiate between the inner classes that are in static context from the classes that are in local (non-static) methods; static inner classes and non-static inner classes. However I cleared my concept on further searching over the topics! Thanks once again.:)

Answer (score 1):

> Java does not allows the object references `this` and `super` to be used in static context but the code above compiles perfectly.

`static` as in "static class" is *not* the same as `static` as in "static context".

All instance methods and constructors have access to `this` and `super`. Since constructors have access to `this` and `super`, initializers of instance fields have access to `this` and `super` as well. A static inner class has no *outer* instance, but it has its own instance. That is what `this` refers to.

In contrast, static methods have no access to `this` and `super`, regardless of the class in which these static methods are defined (top-level, static inner, non-static inner, anonymous, etc.)

Comment: What you cannot reference though in this situation is `Outer.this`. That indeed wouldn't compile.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you meant by : **static as in "static class" is not the same as static as in "static context".**

Comment: @prateek.1729 All I wanted to say is that Java uses keyword `static` to mean two very different things when you declare a class vs. when you declare a method.

Comment: Okay! @dasblinkenlight